# Grep the PIDs of simulator and kill the same using kubectl

Tags: linux, awk, containers, kubectl, ps

I need help with the command where I am trying to grep the PIDs of ecm simulator and kill the same using kubectl :

```
kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep ecm | grep node | awk '{print $2}' "
```

> **Output of the above command:**

```
root      9857     0  0 07:11 ?        00:00:00 bash -c /tmp/simulator/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node /tmp/simulator/ecm_mod.js> /tmp/simulatorEcmResponse.txt
root      9863  9857  0 07:11 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/simulator/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node /tmp/simulator/ecm_mod.js
```

> **Expected output** is:

```
9857 
9863
```

Then further I need to kill the PIDs:

```
kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep ecm | grep node | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
```

When I am executing the same within the service pod it's working but it's giving issues when I am doing via kubectl from outside.

Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

NOTE: There are 2 PIDs which needs to be killed from the below output:

```
eric-service-0:/ # ps -ef | grep ecm | grep node
root      9857     0  0 07:11 ?        00:00:00 bash -c /tmp/simulator/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node /tmp/simulator/ecm_mod.js> /tmp/simulatorEcmResponse.txt
root      9863  9857  0 07:11 ?        00:00:00 /tmp/simulator/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node /tmp/simulator/ecm_mod.js
```

**EDIT:**

Output of the command as asked by @Cyrus below:

[image]

Comment: Add output of `kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep ecm | grep node | hexdump -C"` or `kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "ps -ef | grep ecm | grep node" | hexdump -C` to your question (no comment).

Comment: Possible workaround: `kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "pgrep -f 'node.*ecm'"`

Comment: @Cyrus
Could you please explain -c part? It serves the purpose of what I was looking for in my expected output.

Comment: *pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.* From `man pgrep`. `node.*ecm` is a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @user9275701 did you solve your problem?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, the issue got resolved with the solution as suggested by Cyrus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this this as Community Wiki answer for better visibility. Solution has been provided in comments by @Cyrus.

In Short, OP wanted to Kill/interrupt some process using their `PID's`. OP wanted to do it from cluster level on specific pod/container which included `ecm simulator`.

To do it, commands below were used:

> - `exec` - execute a command in a container
> - `-- bash` - run bash inside container
> - `ps -ef` - list all process  on the system
> - `grep` - serch specific pattern
> - `awk` - pattern scanning and processing language.
> - `xargs` -  build and execute command lines from standard input
> - `kill` - send a signal to a process

In `MANUAL` you can find some information about `ps` flags:

```
To see every process on the system using standard syntax:
          ps -e
          ps -ef
          ps -eF
          ps -ely
```

however each flag will still give another output, like below:

```
-e
 PID TTY  TIME CMD

-ef
UID  PID  PPID  C STIME TTY  TIME CMD
```

Cyrus advised to use following command:

```
kubectl exec eric-service-0 -n cicd --kubeconfig /root/admin.conf -- bash -c "pgrep -f 'node.*ecm'"
```

> `bash -c` - If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.

Also explain in comment:

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout. From man pgrep. node.*ecm is a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).